# TooManyRequestsException: Rate exceeded. while calling codnito-idp admin_get_user function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless

I'm using AWS sdk in my Python Lambda function to get Cognito User's attributes. Like this code:

```
     client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
     try:            
        response = client.admin_get_user(
            UserPoolId=pool_id,
            Username=email
        )
        
        if response is not None and 'Username' in response and 'UserAttributes' in response:
            res = response['UserAttributes']
            return res
        else:
            return None
            
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'UserNotFoundException':
            print("USER NOT FOUND")
            return None
        
        raise e
        
return None
```

When i am trying to get multiple users (around 50 users) using the [AdminGetUser API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html), I am getting TooManyRequestsException error.

What is the default Limit to get users Info from Cognito per second according to the AWS Doc? I see this page [Quotas in Amazon Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html) but I can not see what is this default Limit.

What is the best way to handle this?

Right now I'm planning to wait for 1 second then I will try to get user's attributes from the same user while i get the same exception.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to that Quotas page you mentioned, the limit is 5/second.

> Soft Limits in Amazon Cognito User Pools APIs
> ...
> Admin APIs not listed above.  5

You need to throttle your requests, but the best approach depends on other aspects of your solution.

A few examples:

If your lambda function is being invoked 50 times, one invocation per user, you can set the maximum concurrency for your lambda. (you can find more info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html#configuration-concurrency-reserved) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-troubleshoot-throttling/) ).

If a single lambda call iterates all 50 items at once, then you can add a `time.sleep` call on each iteration, or use some rate limiting library (this one seems to do the task: https://pypi.org/project/ratelimit/). In this case, in addition to this approach, you would probably want to limit the concurrency of your lambda to just 1 .